# How to store a business rule table(9x9)

Tags: c#, sql

I am completely stumped.

I have students that can test their listening skills in a language and the customer wants to be able to change the business rules on demand, the actual business rules and conditions are much more advanced, so I am doing my best to simplify.

I have my object for the student:

```
public class Student {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Score1 { get; set; }
  public int Score2 { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Language { get; set; } 
}
```

Example Business Rule:

There are multiple business rules, but I will give an example below:

- Condition: If the language is Spanish && they are older than 55
- Business Rule Table: *First Row is the score for Score1, First Column is the score for Score2, rest of the data is the value to take when making the comparison.*

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Fail | Fail | Fail | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **2** | Fail | Fail | Fail | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **3** | Fail | Fail | Fail | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **4** | Retake | Retake | Retake | 4 | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **5** | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | 5 | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **6** | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | 6 | Retake | Retake | Retake |
| **7** | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | 7 | Retake | Retake |
| **8** | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | 8 | Retake |
| **9** | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | Retake | 9 |

Examples for how it works:

- Ex1:

  - IF Score1 = 4,
  - AND Score2 = 5,
  - THEN Calculation = Retake
- Ex2:

  - IF Score1 = 6,
  - AND Score2 = 6,
  - THEN Calculation = 6

Requirement:

These business rules need to be put into a SQL table, so they can change the conditions and the outcomes based on the scores, on-demand and track who made the change. Each language(12) will have its own business rules.

Also have the ability to add a business rule on the fly

Questions:

- I know it is not **recommended**, but what is the best way to implement something like this in SQL?

  - Method 1: Two Tables

    - Table1:

      - Conditions for when it should be applied
      - Modified By
      - Modified At (Timestamp)
    - Table2:

      - 81 columns for each of the cells of the Business Rule Table
  - Method 2: One table

    - Table:

      - Conditions for when it should be applied
      - Business rule table as JSON string
      - Modified By
      - Modified At (Timestamp)

Problems:

1. Storing these in SQL will be messy
2. The string values in the BR table are values from a lookup table, that is editable, and will need to be linked

   - ex: "Retake" & "Fail"

Comment: definitely not 81 columns...

Comment: @Jazb lol Yah I know, both of my solutions are terrible and will have all sorts of problems.

Comment: my thoughts are you'll need to have the table containing the data ie 81 rows, and a 'rules engine' in C# that uses logic to output the 'outcome' for each of a row (cell) of data.

Comment: @Jazb So the columns would look something like: Score1, Score2, RuleEngine? Then I can use the scores to find the row I need and then run the RuleEngine?

Comment: i missed the bit where rules are added dynamically - that makes it harder...

Comment: @Jazb yah, but the rule engine suggestion seems like a good idea, I've never used it so I will definitely look into implementing it.